# using BETWEEN in WHERE condition

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'd like the following function to select hotels with an accomodation between a certain `$minvalue` and `$maxvalue`. What would be the best way to do that?

```
function gethotels($state_id,$city,$accommodation,$minvalue,$maxvalue,$limit,$pgoffset)
    {
        $this->db->limit($limit, $pgoffset);
        $this->db->order_by("id", "desc");
        $this->db->where('state_id',$state_id);
        $this->db->where('city',$city);

        // This one should become a between selector
        $this->db->where($accommodation,$minvalue); 

        $result_hotels = $this->db->get('hotels');
        return $result_hotels->result();

   }
```

Comment: is this in kohana, codeigniter or someOtherPHPFramework

Comment: You tagged your question `mysql`, but your code is not `mysql`...

Comment: this has nothing to do with mysql, and you didn't wrote what framework you use.
You could use, moreOrEqual minVal AND lessOrEqual maxVal instead of between

Comment: @om-nom-nom: that's PHP, ok, but he's using a private class or an extension: php `mysql` extension does not have those methods...

Comment: I guess they want to use the `BETWEEN` operator but have no idea how to use it with the database abstraction they use (which seems to be building the query behind the scenes).

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You should use

```
$this->db->where('$accommodation >=', $minvalue);
$this->db->where('$accommodation <=', $maxvalue);
```

I'm not sure of syntax, so I beg your pardon if it's not correct.
Anyway `BETWEEN` is implemented using >=min && <=max.
This is the meaning of my example.

Looking at [this link](http://web.archive.org/web/20120531112954/http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/100048) I think you could write:

```
$this->db->where("$accommodation BETWEEN '$minvalue' AND '$maxvalue'");
```

Comment: @Marco
`$this->db->where("$accommodation BETWEEN $minvalue AND $maxvalue", null, false);`

Is the code required.

Answer (score 9):

In Codeigniter This is simple Way to check between two date records ...

```
$start_date='2016-01-01';
$end_date='2016-01-31';

$this->db->where('date BETWEEN "'. date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start_date)). '" and "'. date('Y-m-d', strtotime($end_date)).'"');
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds correct but some issues maybe creates executing  this query: 
I would suggest:

```
$this->db->where( "$accommodation BETWEEN $minvalue AND $maxvalue", NULL, FALSE );
```

Comment: This type usage genarates SQL Injection Security Issue

Answer (score 0):

Check the following code. Its works for me

```
$dateStart = $this->input->post('dateStart);
$dateTo= $this->input->post('dateTo);
$fromDate=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($dateStart));
$toDate=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($dateTo));
    
$this->db->from('tbl_sales sl');
$this->db->where('DATE(sl.created) >=',$setDate);
$this->db->where('DATE(sl.created) <=',$dateend);
$this->db->get();
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Codeigniter  3.1.11  

  public function getContraMarking($from_date2='',$to_date2='',$acctno2='')
    {
        if($from_date2!='' && $to_date2!='' && $acctno2!='')
        {
            $this->db->select('account_no,txn_date,SUM(pd_amt) AS debit,SUM(cr_amt) AS credit,COUNT(value_date) AS total_count');
            $this->db->from('ut_sbi_reco_paid_master');
            $this->db->where('account_no', $acctno2);
            $this->db->where('txn_date BETWEEN "'. $from_date2. '" AND "'. $to_date2. '" ');
            $this->db->group_by('account_no,txn_date,pd_amt');
            $this->db->order_by("txn_date");

            $query = $this->db->get();
            
            if($query->num_rows() > 0){
                return $query->row();
            }else{  
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can package all of your where conditions as associative elements in the second parameter of a `get_where()` method call.

The greater-than-or-equal-to and less-than-or-equal-to operators merely need to be appended to key string as demonstrated below.

I do not endorse conditionally returning `false` when an object is also possible. PHP has long-supported nullable types and specifically offers null coalescing operations.  Because `row()` returns an object or `null`, I recommend that all model methods which return `row()` data should either return `null` or throw an exception when something "not good" happens while processing.

```
public function getContraMarking(
    string $from_date2 = '',
    string $to_date2 = '',
    string $acctno2 = ''
): ?object {
    if (!$from_date2 || !$to_date2 || !$acctno2) {
        return null;
    }
    return $this->db
        ->select([
           'account_no',
           'txn_date',
           'SUM(pd_amt) debit',
           'SUM(cr_amt) credit',
           'COUNT(value_date) total_count'
        ])
        ->group_by('account_no, txn_date, pd_amt')
        ->order_by('txn_date')
        ->get_where('ut_sbi_reco_paid_master', [
               'account_no' => $acctno2,
               'txn_date >=' => $from_date2,
               'txn_date <=' => $to_date2
        ])
        ->result();
    }
}
```

`get_where()` is not suitable if you want to use column names on both sides of the operator.  In this case, you'll need to use separate `where()` methods with `false` as the escape parameter.

```
->where('col_one >=', 'col_two', false)
->where('col_one <=', 'col_two', false)
->get('ut_sbi_reco_paid_master')
```

Answer (score -1):

You might also encounter an error message. "Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int.

Use single quotes around the dates. E.g.: `$this->db->where("$accommodation BETWEEN '$minvalue' AND '$maxvalue'");`

Comment: This will be potentially insecure/unstable where user input is not sanitized.

Answer (score -1):

I think we can write like this:

```
$this->db->where('accommodation >=', minvalue);
$this->db->where('accommodation <=', maxvalue);
```

without dollar($) sign