# Undefined variable in CodeIgniter 3.1 query

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to use the `BETWEEN` MySQL operator in a CodeIgniter V3 query.

I am getting an "Undefined variable" error. How can I make this work?

`$this->db->between();`

Comment: post your whole code for query?

Comment: reference link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9941521/using-between-in-where-condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `between` like this...

```
$this->db->where("column_name BETWEEN value1 AND value2");
```

OR

like this...

```
$this->db->where('column_name >=',value1);
$this->db->where('column_name <=', value2);
```

For more see here..[using BETWEEN in WHERE condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9941521/using-between-in-where-condition)